# Headings for List of Abbreviations

Tags: sectioning, footer

I'm new to this website. I'm having an issue with `List of abbreviation`, `List of symbols` and `References`. I'm not interested in `bibtex`, or `biblatex` or any other package that handles automatically these things. I simply have to make these two lists. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, ngerman, american,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\symlabel}[1]{\makebox[4cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \dotfill}}
\newenvironment{symbols}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\symlabel} \setlength{\labelwidth}{4cm}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep} \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}{\end{list}}
\fancypagestyle{symb}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyhead[L]{ \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries \hspace{-0.8cm} List of Symbols}} %to set the name of the list of symb
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{symb}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{5} 
\setlength{\voffset}{3.5cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.5cm}
\begin{symbols}
\item[$\lfloor$ $\rfloor$] Approximate the number to the closest lower integer number.
\end{symbols}
\end{document}
```

There are two problems in that:
1. the page number does not appear in the first page
2. the page ends up to be actually longer than the length of the page
3. the pages following the first one the same offset of the headings.
I would like to change the code so that the `voffset` is only for the first page. The page number appear on all the pages including the first one (and I would like it to be Roman starting from a page number that I decide). All the pages including the first one end regularly in order to show the footer.

Comment: You're changing the page layout parameters after `fancyhdr` calling, so this will not really be recognized, also you're changing it directly, which is not recommended, but since you're quite reluctant to use other packages, I don't suggest `geometry` ;-) And you're using a KOMA class with `fancyhdr` :-O

Comment: Don't change \voffset. Whatever is the reason that you are doing it, there is a better way to do it ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how would you use `geometry`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the desired result is. But it seems wrong to me to use a page style for something like a chapter heading.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, ngerman, american,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\Blindtext
\addchap*{\hspace{-.8cm} List of Symbols}
\setcounter{page}{5} 
\begin{description}
\item[$\lfloor$ $\rfloor$] Approximate the number to the closest lower integer number.
\end{description}
\Blindtext
\chapter{A chapter}
\Blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Note that environment `symbols` is not defined in your code. So I have used `description` instead.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

But maybe you want to change the format of the normal chapter headings too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, ngerman, american,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace{-.8cm} #2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\Blindtext
\addchap*{List of Symbols}
\setcounter{page}{5} 
\begin{description}
\item[$\lfloor$ $\rfloor$] Approximate the number to the closest lower integer number.
\end{description}
\Blindtext
\chapter{A chapter}
\Blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]